# Group values by a common value: userid and ipaddress

Tags: php

I'm working on a problem in my database. I'm trying to find the users who are using multiple accounts. 
I have a list of user IDs and used IP addresses, like this:

### Userid // IP Adress

- 1 // IP Address 13
- 2 // IP Address 23
- 1 // IP Address 12
- 4 // IP Address 56
- 9 // IP Address 23
- 5 // IP Address 12
- 2 // IP Address 56

I would like to group it like this. The user with the userid 1 uses the Address 13 and also 12, the user with the id 5 uses also IP Address 12, so they probably are used by the same guy ... and so on.

In the end I need groups like this (if I made no mistake):

### Group 1:

Userid 1, IP Address 13, IP Adress 12, Userid 5

### Group 2:

Userid 2, IP Address 23, Userid 9, Userid 4, IP Address 56

Please help me, I dont get my head arround this!
How can I solve this in a nice way?

### EDIT: Here is my Update and my Solution so far:

Here is my Solution. Actually i think ive created a code Moster. So if anyone could find a nicer solution i would really appreciate it ;)

First of all, ill need this funktion to check if an value is in an multidimensional array:

```
 function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
           return $key;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Following Array contains IP Addresses and Userids:

```
$userids_using_same_ip[$ipadresss] = array("$userid1,$userid2 ....);
```

I will group the Persons who are posting with different accounts or Ipaddresses later in an array called: $sameuserandidcloud

Here is my Code, first off all i will read the $userids_using_same_ip Array:

```
$cloundnr=0;
$sameuserandidcloud = array();
foreach($userids_using_same_ip as $ip => $userids) {
    foreach($userids_using_same_ip[$ip] as $userid) {
       // In this loop i have the $ip and the $userid and im going to store them in the $sameuserandidcloud array

       $checkip = in_array_r($ip, $sameuserandidcloud);
       $checkuserid = in_array_r($userid, $sameuserandidcloud);
       if($checkip==false && $checkuserid==false) {
            //Create new Cloud
            $cloundnr++;
           if(!is_array($sameuserandidcloud[$cloundnr])) $sameuserandidcloud[$cloundnr] = array();
               array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$cloundnr],$ip,$userid);        
           }
           else {
              if($checkip != false) array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$checkip],$ip,$userid);
              elseif($checkuserid != false) array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$checkuserid],$ip,$userid);
           }
    }
}
```

Now i have an Array which contains $ip and $userids which belong together. BUT its not done yet. Because i created this array in a loop there might be ips and ids that have been stored into a Cloud before other, possible matching values where added. So i need to loop the entire array again.

```
    while($loop!=1) {
        $break=0;
        $loop=1;
        foreach($sameuserandidcloud as $cloudid => $idanduseridarray) {
            $break=0;
            foreach($sameuserandidcloud[$cloudid] as $ipOrUserid) {
                $check = in_array_r($ipOrUserid, $sameuserandidcloud);
                if($check != false && $check != $cloudid) {
                    array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$check],$sameuserandidcloud[$cloudid][0]);
                    unset($sameuserandidcloud[$cloudid]);
                    $break = 1;
                    $loop = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($break==1) break;
        }
        echo $break;
    }
```

Here i loop the Values in a Cloud and check if another Cloud contains the value. if so i delete the current one and store all the other values into the matched cloud. Afterwards the loop will stop and another check starts. This is happening over and over again until no more matches are found.

What do you think?! is there a nicer way? i guess i created a monster. But i could find a better solution.

Comment: What exactly you wanted to do? In Database or In Memory Object? or Client Javascript?

Comment: Yes and no. This sound like i am to lazy, but i am actually kinda frustrated after many hours of coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip_address SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Thats also not what i was looking for. I get a list of IPs which are used by a specific user. But this solution doesnt ceck if two users are using the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Actually, I think I've created a code monster. So if anyone could find a nicer solution I would really appropriate it.

First of all, ill need this function to check if an value is in an multidimensional array:

```
 function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
           return $key;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Following Array contains IP Addresses and Userids:

```
$userids_using_same_ip[$ipadresss] = array("$userid1,$userid2 ....);
```

I will group the Persons who are posting with different accounts or Ipaddresses later in an array called: $sameuserandidcloud

Here is my Code, first off all i will read the $userids_using_same_ip Array:

```
$cloundnr=0;
$sameuserandidcloud = array();
foreach($userids_using_same_ip as $ip => $userids) {
    foreach($userids_using_same_ip[$ip] as $userid) {
       // In this loop i have the $ip and the $userid and im going to store them in the $sameuserandidcloud array

       $checkip = in_array_r($ip, $sameuserandidcloud);
       $checkuserid = in_array_r($userid, $sameuserandidcloud);
       if($checkip==false && $checkuserid==false) {
            //Create new Cloud
            $cloundnr++;
           if(!is_array($sameuserandidcloud[$cloundnr])) $sameuserandidcloud[$cloundnr] = array();
               array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$cloundnr],$ip,$userid);        
           }
           else {
              if($checkip != false) array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$checkip],$ip,$userid);
              elseif($checkuserid != false) array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$checkuserid],$ip,$userid);
           }
    }
}
```

Now I have an Array which contains $ip and $userids which belong together. BUT its not done yet. Because I created this array in a loop there might be ips and ids that have been stored into a Cloud before other, possible matching values where added. So i need to loop the entire array again.

```
    while($loop!=1) {
        $break=0;
        $loop=1;
        foreach($sameuserandidcloud as $cloudid => $idanduseridarray) {
            $break=0;
            foreach($sameuserandidcloud[$cloudid] as $ipOrUserid) {
                $check = in_array_r($ipOrUserid, $sameuserandidcloud);
                if($check != false && $check != $cloudid) {
                    array_push($sameuserandidcloud[$check],$sameuserandidcloud[$cloudid][0]);
                    unset($sameuserandidcloud[$cloudid]);
                    $break = 1;
                    $loop = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($break==1) break;
        }
        echo $break;
    }
```

Here I loop the Values in a Cloud and check if another Cloud contains the value. If I delete the current one and store all the other values into the matched cloud. Afterwards the loop will stop and another check starts. This is happening over and over again until no more matches are found.

What do you think? Is there a nicer way? I guess I created an ugly monster. But I could find a better solution

Comment: I think this belongs into your question (probably minus the swear words) so it's clear what you've tried so far and that you're looking for some optimization of the algorithm or an alternative one. and don't make your own code down.

Comment: oh thanks, was my first post here... so i wasn't aware of the edit function. Updated my post and deleted the swear words ;)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the data from your example:

```
+--------+---------+
| userid | address |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 12      |
| 5      | 12      |
| 1      | 13      |
| 2      | 23      |
| 9      | 23      |
| 2      | 56      |
| 4      | 56      |
+--------+---------+
```

for a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE table_27620030 (
    userid INTEGER,
    address INTEGER
);
```

the following query will list all userids that share the same address (and the address):

```
SELECT address, GROUP_CONCAT(userid) userids
  FROM table_27620030
  GROUP BY address
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) > 1
  ORDER BY address
;
```

result:

```
+---------+---------+
| address | userids |
+---------+---------+
| 12      | 1,5     |
| 23      | 2,9     |
| 56      | 2,4     |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: But thats not what i wanted, userid 2 ueses the ip address 56 and also uses the ip address 23. So userid 9, which also uses the ip address 23, belongs into the group with the ipaddress 56... see my problem?

Comment: No, I don't understand. userid 9 never used address 56, so it can never be in the address 56 group. I do understand that you're looking for some grouping but you have problems to actually describe which rules that grouping has. At least I have problems understand your description. However it's very important you give a good description of such a grouping (and that it follows some logic) otherwise you might only make something up that doesn't work (not saying you do, just saying the grouping you comment about is not clear to me).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, my english might be the problem. My basic intention is the follwing. I habe a website where users can post stuff. Every post is stored in my database together with the userid and the ip address. But one poster can use multiple accounts or ipaddresses. So the user with the id 9 can post with different ipaddresses if hes using more then one device or using a different internet accsess. Also one Person can use different userids by using more then one account. I try to get a code where i can find post that are made from one person.

Comment: Userid 9 doesnt uses adderess 56, thats right. but userid 2 does. and userid 2 also uses the address 23! And address 23 is also used by userid 9. So they belong together. I hope you can understand me now. if not, ill try to find a good site in my native language :)

Comment: @user3681084: How many levels deep do you want to descend looking for these releations?

Comment: As deep as necessary. I have like over 5000 entrys. At some point there are no more "groupings" possible... do you know what im looking for?

Comment: as deep as necessary can result in an endless loop. at that point unlimited groupings are possible. does not compute.

Comment: i know, i was thinking about that too but i hoped that there is a nicer solution then looping through the values. ill post my script in some minutes... i was working on a solution based on a foreach and while loop, ill see how it turns out

Comment: well to find relations you will always need to loop through. The SQL query as well does some kind of looping (the database server does), it selects the data and goes through, compares etc. .

Comment: I posted my solution below, i might be interested into your opinion